# Проблемы с задачами из сайтов

Tags: java

Всем привет, у меня проблема с сайтами задач, а точнее acmp.ru и informatics.msk.ru.
Проблемы появились именно с java, c++ c# проблем не было, все решения задач удачно проходили проверку.
решения правильные, но выдает ошибку в обеих сайтах.
позже взяла решение из сайта acmp и хотела попробовать скомпилировать, но IJ IDEA не принимает код/решение из сайта:/
**к примеру, вот мой код**

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main { //имя класса должно быть Main
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String a, b, c;
        String[] data = reader.readLine().replaceAll("", "").split("");
        a = data[0];
        b = data[1];
        c = data[2];

        int q = Integer.parseInt(a);
        int w = Integer.parseInt(c);
        int d;
            System.out.println(d = q + w);

    }
}

вот код из сайта
//Реализация задачи №1 "A+B" на Java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main{ //имя класса должно быть Main
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException{
    new Main().run();
  }
  PrintWriter pw;
  Scanner sc;
  public void run() throws IOException{
    sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    int a=sc.nextInt(), b=sc.nextInt();
    pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
    pw.print(a+b);
    pw.close();
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `но IJ IDEA не принимает код/решение из сайта`, а что значит не принимает? Ошибка при компиляции?

Comment: в основном runtime error

Comment: а код, да, ошибка при компиляции

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.txt (Не удается найти указанный файл)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:639)
 at com.company.Main.run(Main.java:13)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:8)

Comment: В тексте ошибки предельно понятно написано, в чем проблема. Читайте и делайте выводы.

Comment: так я вас прошу помочь с этим...

Comment: @LeylaNyssanbayeva, в ошибке: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.txt (Не удается найти указанный файл) ` :) Кст, а откуда берется файл `input.txt`?

Comment: С чем с этим? Найти вам файл или что?

Comment: @gil9red честно, без понятия

Comment: мой код сайт не принимает, а код из сайта не компилируется, в чем проблема - не могу понять

Comment: Вам уже в ошибке написали в чем проблема и даже в комментариях повторили.

Comment: ясно, очень помогли! спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: (сарказм, нет, хых)

Comment: @LeylaNyssanbayeva, смотрите, вы взяли код и у себя его выполняете и тот ругается на отсутствие файла, соответственно, файл нужно добавить. Создаете файл `input.txt`, кладете в него данные из задачи, запускаете код и смотрите в `output.txt` -- там должен быть ожидаемый результат. Если не знаете где создавать `input.txt`, то создайте сначала `output.txt` (переменные `a` и `b` заранее создайте) и смотрите где в папке проекта он появился, вот в эту же папку (это, кст, называется активной директорией) и помещайте `input.txt`. И не нужно ёрничать :)